# Manually Setting the color of the WP7 System Tray

Tags: windows-phone-7, themes, statusbar

I have read the UI Design Guidelines for WP7 development and am actually a fan of Metro (to a point). However, an app I am developing is requiring custom theming regardless of the user's theme settings.

In general, I just manually set each element that I want to be sure uses a specific color (rather than a theme resource). But I can't seem to find settings regarding the **system tray** (status bar).

I am okay with it showing as long as I can change it's color (failing that though, how can I hide it?).  The color I need it to *always* be is **black**.  Obviously when the dark theme is selected, we are good to go.  But it looks terrible in the light theme to have a big white bar at the top of the app.

Hopefully this is an easy question with some easy to earn rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to change the theme of the system tray (or status bar). You can hide it using the [`SystemTray.IsVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.systemtray.isvisible%28VS.92%29.aspx) property.

Note that I've had trouble trying to set that property within the page constructor (I think it fails when resuming after tombstoning, don't remember exactly). The solution was to place the code in the page's `Loaded` or `OnNavigatedTo` event.

Comment: I guess this will have to be the answer, thanks. I was hoping to change the color, but hiding it will work at least for this app.  In my XAML in the phone:PhoneApplicationPage element I set the shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False" and this worked great, thanks again.

Comment: This is correct. The system tray will always use the system theme colors. If displayed, it is not part of your application so you can not style it.

Comment: @Matt Lacey I was afraid of that. Coming from the iOS world where you have a couple of options, I was hoping it was something I just couldn't find. Ah well, just knowing it isn't possible coupled with the alternative solution from @Praetorian should be enough for my client.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to change that color in mango. `SystemTray.BackgroundColor = Colors.Orange;` In my case it must be inserted in OnNavidatedTo, in constructor it disappeared after 1 second.

Comment: This is the correct answer with the new Mango APIs. You can see a link here to the new Mango APIs for system tray: http://justinangel.net/AllWp7MangoAPIs

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set this in the xaml you can do something like this:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
shell:SystemTray.Opacity="0"
shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="Black"
```

Comment: This should be: shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColour="Black"